# Enable Wireless connection for guest account only

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, user-accounts

I want to enable WiFi internet access for a guest user and disable the same for the administrator at the same time. If I switch users, is there a way that my guest account can access the net while the administrator account is not connected?

Comment: You need more info: enable or disable it where? The router, in the OS, if so, what OS? I have no idea what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Apart from that: Where's the sense in disabling something for the *Admin* (who has all privileges)? I really can't see the use case.

Answer (score 0):

No, Wifi adapter settings are system-level and are not user-specific.